# How to change status bar color when a dialogue is active?

Tags: android, android-dialog, bottom-sheet

I have used BottomSheetDialogFragment and I want to change the status bar color. And also how do I remove the shadow of dialog box from status bar.

[image: BottomSheet Dialog Screenshot]

I have tried this code in my BottomSheetDialogFragment activity.

```
Window window=getDialog().getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#095baf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried windows.invalidate(); after setting the status bar color ?

Comment: you mean getView().invalidate() ? because there is no window.invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
setTitleBar(HomeActivity.this, R.color.status_bar_color);


 public void setTitleBar(Activity activity, int color) {

        Window window = activity.getWindow();

        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color));
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is same as the code I have attached and also, i have to change status bar color in BottomSheetDialogFragment